# CMake C#: add_dependencies adds reference to dependency

Tags: c#, cmake

I've been porting a C#/C++ project from Visual Studio to CMake and I've discovered that for C++ add_dependencies simply defines the build order but for C# projects it adds a reference.  This is problematic for me because there are cases I need to reference one project and not reference another but simply place it first in the build order.  Both of the projects define a class with the same name and having add_dependecies add a reference causes the build to fail due to an ambiguous class name.

Is this the expected behavior of add_dependencies?  Is there another way to set the build order?

Comment: One possibility would be to add a custom target/command that does nothing but acts as an intermediary for dependencies to force build order without (hopefully) passing along the reference. I do not know if this will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with Dorito Johnson's suggestion in his comment.

```
add_custom_target(IndirectDeps echo IndirectDeps )
add_dependencies(IndirectDeps ${NON_LINKING_DEPS})
add_dependencies(App IndirectDeps )
```

I tried several solutions with add_library and the INTERFACE/IMPORTED options but those still referenced the indirect dependencies